# how to copy and paste form in the same application (using c# wins forms)

Tags: c#, winforms

how  to copy and paste form in the same application (using c# wins forms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click on the form and click COPY, then right-click on your project and click PASTE.  This will add a copy of the form to your project.  In order to compile, you then have to change the name of the form to something else (in the main CS file and also in the .designer.cs file).

Comment: duplicate items not supported by resources parameter

Comment: Please note the third sentence in my answer. You need to change the copied form's name in 3 places: at the top of the new .cs file and in the form's constructor, as well as at the top of the new .designer.cs file.

Comment: there duplicate item resources

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the 'source' form, select 'copy' option of the popup menu
Right-click on the project name in the Solution Explorer, select 'paste' option of the popup menu

Comment: duplicate items not supported by resources parameter